# Steady State Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the steady-state solution of the following ODE:
$$(D^2+D+4.25I)y=22.1\cos(4.5t)$$

The answer from the back of my textbook is:
$$y_p = -1.28\cos(4.5t)+0.36\sin(4.5t)$$

I found
$$\begin{align}
y_p&=k_1\sin(4.5t)+k_2\cos(4.5)t\\
y_p'&=4.5k_1\cos(4.5t)-4.5k_2\sin(4.5t)\\
y_p''&=-20.25k_1\sin(4.5t)-20.25k_2\cos(4.5t)
\end{align}$$

But I am not sure how to plug back into initial equation to find the answer $y_p$. I don't understand how $D$ and $I$ work.

Comment: $D$ means "take the derivative". $D^2$ means "take the derivative twice". $I$ means "return what you put in". So you want to compute $y_p''+y_p'+4.25y_p$. Note that this in principle might not be the right thing; the steady state might have a contribution from the homogeneous solution. (However, it turns out that it doesn't, because your homogeneous solutions all vanish at $+\infty$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, we choose the particular solution:

$$y_p(x) = a \cos(4.5 t) + b \sin(4.5 t)$$

We take:

$$(D^2 + D + 4.25 I)y_p = y_p'' + y_p' + 4.25 y_p = 22.1 \cos(4.5t)$$

Using your derivatives and adding all these terms and simplifying, we get:

$$(-4.5 a-16 b) \sin (4.5 t)+(-16 a+4.5 b) \cos (4.5 t) = 22.1 \cos(4.5t)$$

Equating like terms, we have to solve the $2x2$ system:

$$-4.5 a-16 b  = 0 \\-16 a +  4.5 b = 22.1$$

Solving this using your favorite approach (Cramer's, Substitution, Gaussian, ...), we get:

$$a=-1.28,   b=0.36$$

Now you have:

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x)$$

Now all that is left is finding the steady-state.